# Traefik disables TLS 1.2 when using an EC256 certificate

Tags: ssl, tls

I am running Traefik as a reverse proxy in front of my docker containers, I'm including the config files below.

I checked my servers with SSLLabs and I noticed that they do not seem to support TLS 1.2. However, when I change the key type to 4096 RSA keys instead of EC256 ones, and regenerate the certificates, TLS 1.2 works again. The rest of the config and the docker labels are unchanged.

Is this expected behaviour? Does TLS 1.2 not support EC256? Or is this an issue with Traefik? I'm running Traefik version 2.2.11.

Static config:

```
---
ping: {}
log:
  level: INFO
accesslog: {}
providers:
  docker:
    network: ${cfg.network_name}
    exposedbydefault: false
  file:
    watch: true
    filename: ${dynamic_config_file_target}
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ':80'
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: websecure
          scheme: https
  websecure:
    address: ':443'
    http:
      middlewares:
        - security-headers@file
        - compress@file
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt
certificatesresolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: ${cfg.acme.email_address}
      storage: ${cfg.acme.storage}/acme.json
      keyType: EC256
      httpchallenge:
        entrypoint: web
  letsencrypt_dns:
    acme:
      email: ${cfg.acme.email_address}
      storage: ${cfg.acme.storage}/acme.json
      keyType: EC256
      dnschallenge:
        provider: 'route53'
```

Dynamic config:

```
---
http:
  middlewares:
    security-headers:
      headers:
        sslredirect: true
        stsPreload: true
        stsSeconds: ${toString (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)}
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
    compress:
      compress: {}
tls:
  options:
    default:
      minVersion: "VersionTLS12"
      sniStrict: true
      cipherSuites:
        - "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305"
        - "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
        - "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256"
        - "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but are you sure multiple cert resolvers can share the same file storage?

Comment: @DanielB: I am only using one or the other on a given server (depending on whether it is reachable from the internet or not). But indeed, I did not test this. I could rename one of them to be on the safe side. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not Traefik but your configuration:

```
   cipherSuites:
    - "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305"
    - "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
```

These are ciphers suites which explicitly require RSA authentication (that's the RSA in the name) and thus RSA certificates and therefore cannot work with ECC certificates.

```
    - "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256"
    - "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
```

These are TLS 1.3 cipher suites. While they can work with ECC certificates they cannot work with TLS 1.2 either, only with TLS 1.3.

In general it is recommended that you don't explicitly configure any cipher suites unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: That should've been obvious. Adding the ECDSA cipher suites solved the issue. Thanks!